# Xcode iOS phone directory app. core data, sql lite, or

Tags: sql, ios, xcode, core-data

as part of an application I am trying to create, I am looking to data storage solutions. However, I have found many solutions that I can not quite directly apply to the position I am in.

Basically, I want to display in my app, a directory of the staff of my organization. About 100 or so individuals. I want to have generic attributes such as name, email, office#, etc.

However, my goal is to not end up with a static representation of the staff here! (people come and go, switch offices,etc.)

I am looking for the best way (if possible) to maintain a small database that I can administer, and if perhaps, something were to change to someone here, I can make the change and the change will be reflected accordingly.

Please help! I tried submitting my first app but got rejected because I relied on a webview to accomplish this task. This is an internship opportunity and my first real chance at development. Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone directory app can be used to store data in any format you want (xml, json or a proprietary format), because all you do is save a file. But if you choose to use the iPhone app directory to store data you have to write code to read the file (very simple to do) and parse the information (not so simple because the dificulty scales based on the information complexity).

SQLite is a tool to store structured data, providing you a set of tools to access and use the information. You don't need to parse the information, because SQLite does it for you by using transact sql queries.

By now, because you have a list of individuals, and these people are relationed to offices, I think you should use SQLite.

The Code Data is a object graph management, it's a tool to give you more options over data manipulation, and can make your life very easy if you have a lot of data and very complex data models. I don't think you need that for your particular problem, but I think you should learn it at some point.

**UPDATE 1**

You application will have something like:

A core database (sql server, oracle, my sql, etc) will hold your individuals information (your cloud database).

A web page (php, asp.net, etc) will display the core database information in json or xml format (your api).

A iphone app will download the information from the web page and store it in the local SQLite. (you have to decide when you will update the local sql lite, like when is opened, once a week, once a moth, twice a day, etc) (your local storage method).

Display the local SQLite individuals information in the app.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. So if I used SQLite, could I say..create a database that I can edit, and everyone who has the app will see the reflections? Ive been digging and the more I dig the more I get overwhelmed (new to database managament). Ive come across people mentioning the app connecting to a web API, which I am not familiar with.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this will be enough to get started with